# Why does my R script work in RStudio but not in SSMS?

Tags: r, t-sql, ssms, ssms-2016

A script that executes properly in RStudio errors out in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio. Environment details are below.

RStudio

```
platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch: x86_64                      
os: mingw32                     
system: x86_64, mingw32             
status:                                     
major: 3                           
minor: 4.3                         
year: 2017                        
month: 11                          
day: 30                          
svn rev: 73796                       
language: R                           
version.string: R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname: Kite-Eating Tree
```

SSMS

```
Product: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3 (9600)
Platform: NT x64
Version: 13.0.5216.0
```

Here is the code that I am attempting to execute.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R',
@script = N'
library(RODBC)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

connectionString <- odbcConnect(dsn="KMhivehttp")
goldInstrumentApps <- sqlQuery(connectionString, "select CAST(instrumentapps_event.event AS varchar(8000)) AS event, 
                               instrumentapps_event.load_ts, 
                               instrumentapps_event.data_dt from dmfwk_gold.instrumentapps_event")

goldInstrumentDF <- data.frame(goldInstrumentApps)

formattedDF <- transform(goldInstrumentDF, instrumentapps_event.load_ts = 
       ymd_hms(as.character(goldInstrumentDF$instrumentapps_event.load_ts)))
'
```

Here is some info on the data I am processing:

```
str(goldInstrumentDF)
```

This returns:

> STDOUT message(s) from external script:  'data.frame': 411 obs. of  3
>   variables: $ event  : Factor w/ 408 levels
>   "{\"time\":\"2018-11-12T14:45:01.133Z\",\"application\":\"com_ldo_suchma_loma_cw_prod-salesorderreturnsservice_1.1.6\",\"verb\":"|
>   **truncated**,..: 1 18 27 29 28 22 8 16 17 24 ... $ load_ts: Factor w/ 42 levels "2018/11/13 19:20:58",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... $ data_dt:
>   Factor w/ 33 levels "**HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**",..: 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
>   3 ...

This is the code that causes the error:

```
formattedDF <- transform(goldInstrumentDF, instrumentapps_event.load_ts = 
       ymd_hms(as.character(goldInstrumentDF$instrumentapps_event.load_ts)))
```

This is the error:

> Error in data.frame(list(event = c(1L, 18L, 27L, 29L, 28L, 22L, 8L,
>   16L,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 411, 0 Calls:
>   source ... transform -> transform.data.frame -> do.call -> data.frame
>
> Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information. Error in
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for
>   more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   .Call Execution halted Warning message: closing unused RODBC handle 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have 2 date-time variables that are encoded as a factor (one in YYYY/MM/DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ format and the other in "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS") . That's not usually an effective situation. Character data-class might be better. Sorting would be possible. R won't sort factors. Also Your version of R is out-dated.

Comment: Also the str() output doesn't match up with the column names being used in the transform call.There's no column named `instrumentapps_event.load_ts`. Perhaps you should use `goldInstrumentDF$load_ts` inside the call to `as.character`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: My stupidity never ceases to amaze me. You're right: I was calling the wrong column. Thank you for your help!